# Gadget portal vs browser desktop paradigm

Tags: javascript, user-interface, desktop

I wanted a somewhat objective analysis between usage of a gadgets-in-a-portal-container paradigm vs a browser-desktop-with-inline-windows paradigm. Examples of the two would be [shindig](http://shindig.apache.org/) and [jquery desktop](http://sonspring.com/journal/jquery-desktop) respectively. I wanted to know the basis on which one should choose one over the other. The solution is meant to cater to an enterprise use case where we need representation of summary data (in various pictorial forms) with ability to drill down from the summary to detailed data of increasing granularity (in data grids say) with workflows involving edit operations on the detailed data where at the end of the edit operation, the summary data (pies, bars, etc.) should get refreshed.

Also, it was conveyed to me by a colleague that the browser desktop paradigm has not really taken off since its inception in early 2000, other than in a Chromebook kind of a device. There is also [ExtJS from Sencha](http://cdn.sencha.com/ext-4.1.1a-gpl/examples/desktop/desktop.html) which seems to also support a browser desktop.

I know that the choice of the paradigm is usually subject to the application use cases (a small subset of which I have tried to outline above) that we may want to solve and the richness of the user experience we wish to deliver, but I wanted to know if there are any general guidelines from the UI gurus that newbies can appreciate and use to make an objective choice?

Thanks in advance!